# moving moment to dayjs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I was using moment in my react application earlier I changed to dayjs
before code:

```
moment.duration(moment().diff(moment(timeString)));
```

after code :

```
dayjs.duration(dayjs().diff(dayjs(timeString)));
```

I am getting this error:

```
dayjs.duration is not a function
```

Comment: Did you installed the [duration plugins](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/duration) ?

Answer (score 1):

Day.js doesn't have the duration function built-in as Moment.js does. However, there is a plugin for Day.js named duration which you can use.

Here's how you can use the plugin:

First, you need to install the plugin:

```
npm install dayjs duration
```

Then, in your code, you need to import and extend Day.js with it:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration'

dayjs.extend(duration)

// Now you can use dayjs.duration
const diff = dayjs.duration(dayjs().diff(dayjs(timeString)));
```

Remember, the duration plugin should be loaded whenever you want to use the duration function.

Also, be aware that when working with durations in Day.js, the API is slightly different from Moment.js. For example, to get the duration in minutes, you would use diff.asMinutes(), not diff.minutes().

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to create a duration using Day.js, but there might be an issue with how you're using the duration function. Here's a corrected version

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const duration = require('dayjs/plugin/duration');
dayjs.extend(duration);

const timeString = '2023-01-01T12:00:00';
const timeDifference = dayjs.duration(dayjs().diff(dayjs(timeString)));

console.log(timeDifference.asHours()); // or any other method you want to use
```